# Digits before and/or after decimal

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'd like to match the patterns `digits.digits`, `digits.[digits]`, and `[digits].digits` with regex in Python.

Source for this: the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) state than a numeric constant can take any of these forms:

```
digits
digits.[digits][e[+-]digits]
[digits].digits[e[+-]digits]
digitse[+-]digits
```

Where brackets indicate optionality and `digits` is one or more digits, 0-9.

I'd like to match a small subset of this syntax,

```
digits.[digits]
[digits].digits
```

In other words, at least one digit must be before or after the decimal point.  (Or, before and after.)

From the string `numbers = '.42 5.42 5. .'`, the call to `re.findall(regex, numbers)` should return `['.42', '5.42', '5.']`.

What I have tried is an if-then conditional, `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`:

```
regex = r'(\d+)?(?(1)\.\d*|\.\d+)'
```

The issue is that this mandates a capturing group, which `(1)` references, and `re.findall(r'(\d+)?(?(1)\.\d*|\.\d+)', numbers)` gives `['', '5', '5']` because it's grabbing the capture group.

Please ignore word boundaries, leading zeros, exponential notation, etc for now.  A naive regex would be:

```
regex = r'\d+\.\d*|\d*\.\d+'
```

But as the complexity of the syntax grows, I'd prefer not to just `|`-together separate regexes.

How can I structure this to have `re.findall(regex, numbers)` return the list above?

Comment: You may use `re.finditer`, you know.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as in `[i.group(0) for i in re.finditer(r'(\d+)?(?(1)\.\d*|\.\d+)', numbers)]`?

Comment: Your 'naive regex' looks perfect. What's wrong with using a `|`?

Comment: If you mean scale in performance, does the lookaround perform better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you may use your regex with `re.finditer` to get the first group with  each whole match value (`[x.group(0) for x in re.finditer(regex, numbers)]`), you may also get the values you need with

```
re.findall(r'(?=\.?\d)\d*\.\d*', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NHR2Ve/2)

**Details**

- `(?=\.?\d)` - a positive lookahead that requires an optional `.` followed with a digit immediately to the right of the current location
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d*` - 0+ digits

So, even though `\d*` in the consuming pattern can match 0 digits, the lookahead requires at least one there.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/30gFbp):

```
import re
s=".42 5.42 5. ."
print(re.findall(r'(?=\.?\d)\d*\.\d*', s))
# => ['.42', '5.42', '5.']
```